# How to extract identified inner and outer contours using EmguCV?

Tags: c#, image-processing, contour, emgucv, medical

I'm doing a project to process brain injuries using Image Processing. In order to  improve its accuracy, I need to extract only the brain matter from the skull.

Using EmguCV I was able to identify the inner and outer contours (Blue and Dark blue). Is there anyway to extract these identified contours into another image?

```
Image<Gray, byte> grayImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(bitmap);
Image<Bgr, byte> color = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap);

grayImage = grayImage.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(220), new Gray(255));

using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())
{
    for (Contour<Point> contours = grayImage.FindContours(
        Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_TREE, storage); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
    {
        Contour<Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.015, storage);
        if (currentContour.BoundingRectangle.Width > 20)
        {
            CvInvoke.cvDrawContours(color, contours, new MCvScalar(100), new MCvScalar(255), -1, 2, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED, new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

EmguCV 2.2.2

[image: Identified Contours]

Expected output:

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1):

A good way to achieve that is to use masks, as in this [C++ example](https://www.bytefish.de/blog/extracting_contours_with_opencv.html). I took [this image](https://www.eurorad.org/case/12781) as an example (licensed under a CC-NC-SA license).
You first extract the inner contour of the skull with `CvInvoke.FindContours`:

[image]

Then you create a mask with `CvInvoke.FillPoly` based on the inner contour:

[image]

Finally you can copy the original image to the mask image and you will get only the inside of the skull.

[image]

Full code is available here. Note that I used EmguCV 4.8.1 so some changes were necessary.

```csharp
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Util;

namespace emgutest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string testFile = "test.jpg";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap testImage;

            using (var stream = new FileStream(testFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                testImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream);
            }

            var color = testImage.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
            var grayImage = color.Convert<Gray, byte>();

            grayImage = grayImage.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(220), new Gray(255));

            // Extract contour
            VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

            CvInvoke.FindContours(grayImage, contours, hierarchy, RetrType.Tree, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

            // Draw contour on original image
            var color_contour = color.Copy();
            CvInvoke.DrawContours(color_contour, contours, 1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), 2);  // Inner contour (-1 for all, 0 for outer)

            color_contour.Save("output_contour.jpg");

            // Create mask
            Mat output_image = color.Mat;
            VectorOfVectorOfPoint inner_contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint(contours[1]);  // Select inner contour only

            Mat blackedOut = new Mat(color.Size, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
            blackedOut.SetTo(new MCvScalar(0, 0, 0));  // Full black image

            Mat mask = new Mat(grayImage.Size, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
            CvInvoke.FillPoly(mask, inner_contours, new MCvScalar(255), LineType.AntiAlias);
            CvInvoke.DrawContours(mask, contours, -1, new MCvScalar(0), 2, LineType.Filled);

            // Copy image to mask
            output_image.CopyTo(blackedOut, mask);

            blackedOut.Save("output.jpg");

        }
    }
}
```